# Git on Yosemite keeps asking for remote username and password

Tags: git, github, osx-yosemite

I've updated to OS X Yosemite. When running any git command that has to do with the remote repo (pull, fetch, etc) the terminal keeps asking for my github username and password (the remote is on github). If I perform these actions from the github client for mac, it doesn't ask for credentials.

My git config file is fine. My SSH key is fine too. I tried to reinstall the git command line tools from the Github app with no success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be that your repo remote-url is using https instead of ssh? I know that Mavericks did this to all of my repos on one rare occasion.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Run following on command line.

**git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain**

Then run your git command. Here is the link that helped me figure out.
https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Comment: After updating git from 1.9 to 2.x, this was the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem that Git was not working because XCode has overwritten the git command. So you have to open XCode the first time and he install all other components. After that it was working.

Comment: @NikosM. did you install using `homebrew`?